# Run task scheduler from another server remotely

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler

Is it possible to run a task scheduler from another task scheduler in another server !?
All my tasks are for running PowerShell

Best regards,

Comment: You may want to rewrite the question if you want help. I have no idea what your asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Open Task Scheduler, click Action -> Connect to another computer..., then enter the name of the remote computer and click OK.

Sean.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/10/15/introducing-the-windows-7-resource-kit-powershell-pack.aspx

Check the Task Scheduler Module.

Import-Module TaskScheduler